# Is it possible to serialize as known default format in custom serializer?

Tags: scala, json4s

I have to deserialize JSON response that can have one of the fields set to different objects (with just one common field). Real-life model is rather complex, but for example we can represent it by two case classes extending sealed trait:

```
sealed trait Item {
  val itemType: String
}

case class FirstItem(
  itemType: String = "FirstItem",
  firstProperties: SomeComplexType
) extends Item

case class SecondItem(
  itemType: String = "SecondItem",
  secondProperties: SomeOtherComplexType,
  secondName: String,
  secondSize: Int
) extends Item
```

Since Json4s does not know how to handle that object I wrote custom serializer:

```
object ItemSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Item](_ => ({
  case i: JObject => 
    implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats
    (i \ "itemType").extract[String] match {
      case "FirstType" => i.extract[FirstItem]
      case "SecondItem" => i.extract[SecondItem]
    }
}, {
  case x: Item => x match {
    case f: FirstItem => JObject() //TODO
    case s: SecondItem => JObject() //TODO
  }
}))
```

First part - deserialization is not perfect as it depends strongly on type-field, but its fine for my needs. The problem is the second part - serialization. In examples I've found people usually write down every field step by step, but usually, they serialize some simple objects. In my case this object has multiple levels and over 60-80 fields in total so it would result in rather messy and hard to read code. So I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it, as both `FirstItem` and `SecondItem` can be deserialized using only `DefaultFormats`. Is there any way to tell Json4s that if object matches the given type it should be serialized with default format?

Comment: Could you please explain your use case? Can some solution like storing of original response and copying it be replacement for the serialization?

Comment: No, copying it wont help. I'm getting that response from third party API and I need to read data from nested object, but depending on type of object it has different structure and those objects can be returned either as single object or array of objects, where different types are allowed within single array. There are few such objects in various places in that API and in real case there are much more types than two. So I do not want to handle it separately in each case, I want something generic.

Comment: @MateuszGruszczynski Are you opened to using other libs than json4s?

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc I would like to keep json4s as it either would require to rewrite a lot or to introduce redundant library. We were using circe but due to a lot of complex models it was extremely slow on the compilation (up to 10-15m in CI/CD) and since we do not make many requests it doesn't have to be fast on runtime so we chose Json4s.

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some digging in various examples and turns out that it is is possible and super simple. There is an `org.json4s.Extraction.decompose()` method that handles everything e.g.:

```
object ItemSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Item](_ => ({
  case i: JObject => 
    implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats
    (i \ "itemType").extract[String] match {
      case "FirstType" => i.extract[FirstItem]
      case "SecondItem" => i.extract[SecondItem]
    }
}, {
  case x: Item => 
    implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats
    x match {
      case f: FirstItem => Extraction.decompose(f)
      case s: SecondItem => Extraction.decompose(s)
    }
}))
```

However, my solution to the described problem was wrong. I don't need to specify extra serializers. What I needed was just a companion object for trait, that contains constructors for each format of data and Json4s handles everything perfectly, e.g.:

```
object Item{
  def apply(
    itemType: String, 
    firstProperties: SomeComplexType
  ): Item = FirstItem(itemType, firstProperties)

  def apply(
    itemType: String, 
    secondProperties: SomeOtherComplexType, 
    secondName: String, secondSize: Int
  ): Item = SecondItem(itemType, secondProperties, secondName, secondSize)
}
```